# How to deserialize a JSON Map<Int, Map<String, String>> using gson?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, serialization, gson

guys!

How can I deserialize a JSON Map<Int, Map<String, String>> using gson or any other library?

I want to convert this string:

```
{
    "123": {
        "KEY_ONE": "blablabla",
        "KEY_TWO": "blablabla",
    },
    "456": {
        "KEY_ONE": "blablabla"
        "KEY_TWO": "blablabla"
    }
}
```

Into this: Map<Int, Map<String, String>>

I tried these two options:

`

```
var gson = Gson()

// Try 1:
var mapper = gson.fromJson(payload, Map::class.java)

// Try 2:
val mapper = object: TypeToken<Map<Int, Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType()
var xmlBase64 = gson.fromJson(payload, type::class.java) //Map<Int, Map<String, String>>
```

`

On both attempts, I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Try 2" using `TypeToken` is the correct approach but you are using it incorrectly: When calling `Gson.fromJson` just pass `type` directly as argument (without `::class.java`):

```kotlin
val type = object: TypeToken<Map<Int, Map<String, String>>>(){}.type
val xmlBase64: Map<Int, Map<String, String>> = gson.fromJson(payload, type)
```

"Try 1" using a raw `Map` might also work because Gson uses default types based on the JSON value types (e.g. JSON object as `Map`, JSON string as `String`), but it is not type safe and you will encounter `ClassCastException`s when you try to use the deserialized data but the JSON data had a different format or when your code assumes the wrong types.

When using Gson 2.10 or newer, prefer the [`fromJson` overloads with `TypeToken` parameter](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.io.Reader,com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken)) (that is, omit the `.type` call on the `TypeToken`) because they are type-safe:

```kotlin
val typeToken = object: TypeToken<Map<Int, Map<String, String>>>(){}
val xmlBase64 = gson.fromJson(payload, typeToken)
```

However, the `IllegalStateException` you are experiencing also indicates that your JSON data is in an incorrect format. Possibly it is wrapped inside extra double quotes (e.g. `"{...}"` instead of `{...}`)? Try to log the JSON data (or set a breakpoint) and verify that is has the expected format. Besides that the sample JSON data you provided has some incorrect commas; use a tool such as https://jsonlint.com/ to verify that it is valid JSON.

Comment: Hey, @Marcono1234!!!

First of all, thank you for your time and your answers, they helped a lot!

I tested both suggestions made by you and both worked!!

And really, about the payload, I ended up getting confused when sending it, instead of sending a JSON, I ended up getting another payload of type XML by mistake.

As I am using GSON 2.10, I chose to use your second suggestion:

val typeToken = object: TypeToken<Map<Int, Map<String, String>>>(){}
val xmlBase64 = gson.fromJson(payload, typeToken)

Again, thank you so much!